# LaTeX - Изменить стиль списка определений

Tags: latex

Стандартный список определений LateX строит элементы вроде такого

```
ТерминЖирным Определяющий текст обычным
```

а хотелось бы вот так:

```
ТерминЖирным 
   Определяющий текст обычным
```

Уточняю вопрос: можно ли внутри списка определений выполнить переход на новый абзац, да ещё и со сдвигом абзаца вправо?

Список очень длинный, так что хотелось бы что-то попроще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```tex
\begin{description}
  \item[aaa] \hfil \\ A-a-a-a a-a-a-a a-a-a-a!
  \item[bbb] \hfil \\ B-b-b-b b-b-b-b b-b-b-b!
\end{description}
```

Comment: Получилось! Именно то, что нужно. Большое спасибо!